# Tracing XML child

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, children, trace

I want to trace one button element at a time. But not only the content of the button.

I would like to get to trace:

```
 <BUTTON XY="100,300" TOMAP="SECOND" WARLEVEL="02_deamon" REQUIRE="03_cityMonsters" UNTIL="04_chaosBlaBla">Description1...</BUTTON>
```

However, I know the button does contain the data, as it traces REQUIRE. The problem is only the tracing-part. Either it traces too much as map.toString() does, or too little as button.toString() does.

In flash:

```
...
var map:XML = world.MAP[_map];

trace(map.toString());
```

does what I want, traces:

```
<MAP NAME="FIRST">
     <BUTTON XY="100,300" TOMAP="SECOND" WARLEVEL="02_deamon" REQUIRE="03_cityMonsters" UNTIL="04_chaosBlaBla">Description1...</BUTTON>
     <BUTTON XY="100,400" TOMAP="FIRST" WARLEVEL="03_cityMonsters" REQUIRE="03_cityMonsters" UNTIL="04_chaosBlaBla">Description2...</BUTTON>
     <BUTTON XY="200,300" TOMAP="PREBOSS">GO-TO STUFF</BUTTON>
     <BG>backgrounds/firstBg.jpg</BG>
</MAP>
```

but

```
for (var i = 0; i < map.BUTTON.length(); i++) {

    var button:XML = map.BUTTON[i];
    if (button.@REQUIRE != undefined) {
        trace("found REQUIRE ");  // Traces: found REQUIRE 
    }
    trace(button.toString());

}
```

Does NOT do what I want, traces:

```
Description1...
```

XML-File:

```
<WORLD>
  <MAP NAME="FIRST">
    <BUTTON XY="100,300" TOMAP="SECOND" WARLEVEL="02_deamon" REQUIRE="03_cityMonsters" UNTIL="04_chaosBlaBla" >Description1...</BUTTON>
    <BUTTON XY="100,400" TOMAP="FIRST"  WARLEVEL="03_cityMonsters"  REQUIRE="03_cityMonsters" UNTIL="04_chaosBlaBla" >Description2...</BUTTON>
    <BUTTON XY="200,300" TOMAP="PREBOSS" >GO-TO STUFF</BUTTON>

    <BG>backgrounds/firstBg.jpg</BG>
  </MAP>
  <MAP NAME="SECOND">
    <BUTTON XY="100,300" TOMAP="FIRST"  WARLEVEL="03_cityMonsters"  REQUIRE="03_cityMonsters" UNTIL="04_chaosBlaBla" >Description3...</BUTTON>
    <BUTTON XY="100,250" TOMAP="SECOND" >Description4..</BUTTON>
    <BG>backgrounds/firstBg.jpg</BG>
  </MAP>
</WORLD>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `toXMLString()`

```
trace(button.toXMLString());
```

Comment: Hey attach this to your answer: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#toXMLString()

Comment: @Cherniv I wanna keep the answer as simple as it can be, cause the link might changed or disabled.

Comment: As you wish , but note that this link links to the official documentation ;)

Comment: @Cherniv I'd like to put it in the first comment and mark it as useful :)